# do not stop execution when Warning in Odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have a scenario where i have to cancel different tasks, but the requirement is if the task state is not created it will show popup message, but for other task which are created, those will be cancelled.
But when i implemented as soon as i show warning, it stops the execution and other tasks are not cancelled.
below is my tried code:

```
@api.multi
def cancel_tasks(self):
    remained_tasks = []
    for record in self:
        if record.status_id.active and record.status_id.name != 'Created':
            remained_tasks.append(record.name)

        if record.status_id.active and record.status_id.name == 'Created':
            record.action_cancel()
            self._cr.commit()

    if len(remained_tasks) > 0:
        msg = 'Invalid Status for Tasks'
        for tasks in remained_tasks:
            msg += ','+str(tasks)
        raise openerp.exceptions.Warning(msg)
```

The Problem is if any task is not in created state, the process stops and other tasks can not be cancelled also.

Thanks,

## Update:

The Records can be saved if add the line self._cr.commit(), but now when you see the popup for error, you press OK and then need to refresh the page manually to see the latest state. Is it possible to refresh the page as soon as you press OK button in Warning Popup.

Comment: Have not tried this myself, but raising an exception of type openerp.exceptions.RedirectWarning might be what you are looking for. You can try and redirect the user to the page with the updated content.